# Move home directory in Ubuntu

Tags: bash, users

We are running an Ubuntu server and have several people in the company that need to have SSH access. This is a web server and the different sites reside in /home. When I create a new user on the server with adduser "username" then a new directory is automatically created in /home. As the sites also reside here, I'd like to re-structure this and actually create /home/users/ and manage all user-directories from there. However, with adduser I can not set the home directory, and I can not find a way to change this easily.

If I use useradd and the -m option, I can specify the home directory. However, my bash is different. It only shows "$" instead of the server name and current directory, as is default (user@server:/home/). Also, tabbing to get the full filename does not work anymore. This should have to do with bash settings, but I can not get this to work.

So, the question is:

- Is there an easy way to change the home directory when using adduser? OR:
- How can the bash configuration be fixed when using useradd?

Note: I compared .bashrc and .profile for the new user with useradd and adduser, and they are identical.

Comment: You may be getting `/bin/sh` for the user's login shell which doesn't have tab completion and has a much simpler prompting capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [**adduser**](http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser) man page you will see that there is a -d or --home command line option which allows you to specify a users home directory.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! This was extremely simple and I have no idea how I did not find this before. If somebody knows what happens to bash when you use useradd I am still interested, but at least the user adding problem is solved!

Comment: In Red Hat / Fedora land, you can set `HOME` in /etc/default/useradd to change the default. Not sure if that's the same in Ubuntu.